# Fast Android web browser, open source

Tags: android, open-source, web-browser

I am currently using Firefox on Android, but it is really unnecessarily slow.  For instance, whenever I open a page from another app it seems to first load the page I had last seen, before even attempting to load the page I want to open. Loading the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) website takes more than 10 seconds on a Nexus 5 (*yes rather old phone but I am sure a 2.26 GHz quad-core with 2GB RAM can do better*).

So I am looking for another web browser.

Requirements:

- Fast even on 5-year old phones and 2019 low-end phones. When clicking a link to Software Recommendation from another app such as GMail, the page should load in less than 10 seconds, the faster the better.
- 100% open source.
- As close to W3C standards as possible.
- Bookmarks, history, "request desktop site" features.
- Runs on Android 7.1.2+

Comment: Interestingly, Firefox Focus loads the Software Recommendations website in under 2 seconds on an old smartphone.  It meets all your requirements except having bookmarks and history, so I didn't put it as an answer.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: Nice, I did not know about that product, great news! I really need bookmarks and history though. I guess that if a privacy browser can be fast, then a browser with a bit more caching might be even faster :-)

Comment: When you say it requires "history", would forward and back buttons suffice, or do you need a history list where you can see the URL and/or page title of recently visited websites?  I'm guessing the latter, but I think I found an answer if it's the former!

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: Either a list, or preferably URL autocompletion based on previously visited websites. I need that because there are many websites that I visit several times, for instance GitHub projects, and finding them via a search engine again would take much more time.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Lightning](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/acr.browser.lightning/) web browser which is licensed under *MPL (Mozilla Public License) 2.0*. When I was having an old phone I used to use this one works nice.

> Lightweight web browser with following features:
>
> - Fast Start Times
> - Small Footprint
> - Smooth Scrolling
> - Long-press a tab to delete it
> - Long-press the back button to exit the browser
> - Ad blocker

The App size is only 2.2MB

Here are some screen-shots:

[image]  
[image]   
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On a comparable phone (Samsung Galaxy S5) I load this site in under 3 seconds in Firefox. The likely difference is I'm using the [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/ublock-origin/) and [uMatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/umatrix/) extensions. Javascript, especially that used by ads, is likely the culprit. Filtering it out can greatly improve your experience.